# Pulling 0-sized golang chan

Tags: go, race-condition, channel, goroutine

My use-case is the following: I need to send POST requests to `0...N` subscribers, which are represented by a targetUrl. I want to limitate the max number of goroutine to let's say, 100. My code (simplified) is the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "errors"
)

const MAX_CONCURRENT_NOTIFICATIONS = 100

type Subscription struct {
    TargetUrl string
}

func notifySubscribers(subs []Subscription) {
    log.Println("notifySubscribers")
    var buffer = make(chan Subscription, len(subs))
    defer close(buffer)

    for i := 0; i < MAX_CONCURRENT_NOTIFICATIONS; i++ {
            go notifySubscriber(buffer)
    }

    for i := range subs {
            buffer <- subs[i]
    }
}

func notifySubscriber(buffer chan Subscription) {
    log.Println("notifySubscriber")
    for {
            select {
            case sub := <-buffer:
                    log.Println("sending notification to " + sub.TargetUrl)

                    resp, err := failPost()
                    if err != nil {
                            log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("failed to notify %s. error: %s", sub.TargetUrl, err.Error()))
                    } else {
                            resp.Body.Close()

                            if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
                                    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s responded with %d", sub.TargetUrl, resp.StatusCode))
                            }
                    }
            }
            log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("buffer size: %d", len(buffer)))
    }
}

func failPost() (*http.Response, error) {
    return &http.Response{
            StatusCode: http.StatusBadRequest,
    }, errors.New("some bad error")
}

func main() {
    log.Println("main")
    var subs []Subscription
    subs = append(subs, Subscription{TargetUrl: "http://foo.bar"})
    subs = append(subs, Subscription{TargetUrl: "http://fizz.buzz"})

    notifySubscribers(subs)
    select {}
}
```

The output is the following:

`2018/01/24 10:52:48 failed to notify . error: some bad error
2018/01/24 10:52:48 buffer size: 1
2018/01/24 10:52:48 sending notification to 
2018/01/24 10:52:48 failed to notify . error: some bad error
2018/01/24 10:52:48 buffer size: 0
2018/01/24 10:52:48 sending notification to 
2018/01/24 10:52:48 failed to notify . error: some bad error
... and so on till I SIGINT the program`

So basically it means that I've successfuly send the notifications to the right people, but I still continue to send to empty targetUrl because I read from an empty chan.

What is wrong ?

[EDIT] Workaround, but I don't like it

```
for {
    select {
        case sub, more := <-buffer:
            if !more {
                return
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are closing the buffer but your `notifySubscriber` is still listening on the buffer. A closed channel always returns the default type value(in this case an empty `Subscription` with empty `TargetURL`). Hence, you are getting an empty string.

Scenarios:

- If you want to keep the goroutines running, then don't close the buffer.
- Stop the goroutines once the work is done and then close the buffer.

Comment: Is my edit valid then ? This way the goroutine closes itself

Comment: it is valid, yes

Answer (score 1):

From the spec:

> For a channel c, the built-in function close(c) records that no more
>   values will be sent on the channel. It is an error if c is a
>   receive-only channel. Sending to or closing a closed channel causes a
>   run-time panic. Closing the nil channel also causes a run-time panic.
>   After calling close, and after any previously sent values have been
>   received, receive operations will return the zero value for the
>   channel's type without blocking. The multi-valued receive operation
>   returns a received value along with an indication of whether the
>   channel is closed.

The last sentence means that `sub, more := <-buffer`, more will be `false` if `buffer` is closed.

However, in your case, the code can use some improvement.

First, it makes no sense to use a `select` statement where there are only one `case`. It would just act the same without the `select`.

Second, in cases that the recieving channel is guaranteed to return, `range` over channel can be used. So your code can be changed to:

```
func notifySubscriber(buffer chan Subscription) {
    log.Println("notifySubscriber")
    for sub:= range buffer {
        //Code here...
    }
}
```